# What is the development platform for Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

If I want to develop for Windows Phone 7, what should I learn? XNA, Silverlight or other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has not yet announced what the development environment will be.  They say they'll get more [in-depth at MIX](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/wmdev/archive/2010/02/15/windows-phone-7-series-going-big-for-developers-at-mix10.aspx).  If I were a betting man, I'd guess you'll get XNA out of the box, followed by some light version of Silverlight.

***EDIT***

I'd say it's no longer a guess that it will be Silverlight and XNA just based on the [MIX sessions for Windows Phone](http://live.visitmix.com/Sessions#/tags/WindowsPhone).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make applications (or even simple games), choose silverlight. If you want to make 3d games, or games with xbox live integration, choose xna :-)